# Not able to manually set the gps location in DDMS in android

Tags: android

I'm using vista & cannot do a "geo fix" since telnet is not available.
I've disabled firewall and i'm using Zoc/Pro app which is a telnet app to connect
to the emulator. I'm not able to connect using localhost:5554 but instead 127.0.0.1:5554
But after connecting i did a  -> geo fix 47.33 -52.74 , i got a message OK.
But if i put in below code n chk it shows 0.0 0.0

```
locMgr = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = locMgr.getProviders(true);
    System.out.println("providers " + providers);   


    Location lc = null;

    for(int i=providers.size()-1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
            lc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
            if(lc==null)
                    break;
    }

    double[] gpsCord = new double[2];
    if(lc!=null) {

            gpsCord[0] = lc.getLatitude();
            gpsCord[1] = lc.getLongitude();
    }
    System.out.println("Latitude = " + gpsCord[0] + " " + "Longitude = " + gpsCord[1]);  //Prints 0.0 0.0
```

How can i get the locations ??

Answer (score 0):

To set mock location:

In DDMS view open Emulator Control.

There you can see a Panel Location Controls--> set 'Manual' Tab--> Check Decimal--> Give location in the fields Ex. (-12.084095 as lat & 65.422006 as lng).

To get this working open the Device Settinngs-->Applications-->Development-->Allow Mock location--> Check It.

Then you can successfully provide and retrieve mock location.

Comment: Yes mock location is turned on!  and also tried setting the co-ordinates through ddms still no luck :(

Comment: i've also added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> but again same problem